Limpiar GIT LOG ( No me funcina con la letra Q )
una consulta, cuando quiero limpiar el git log que me muestra los commit hechos y presiono la tecla Q no me funciona. Hay otra manera para limpiarlo sin que se salga del git log? Desde ya gracias.

Quieres borrar el historial? Como tal creo que no se puede. Tal vez quieras hacer un rebase? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8969617
